# mvc4 and WebApi causes duplicate controllers

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm getting my feet wet with MVC4 and Web API. But I'm having trouble understanding the fact that I now need an Items controller that returns the data (the Web API part), and another Items controller to return the view that displays the list of Items.

Is there a convention or a simpler way to do this in MVC4? My Controllers folder is getting cluttered with names like ItemController and ItemsController, one for the Web API and one for the view.

Comment: Place the Web Api controllers in a folder called Api in the Controllers folder

Answer (score 5):

You could separate your Web API controllers in a sub-folder or even a separate class library project from the main application to avoid the terrible cluttering of the famous `Controllers` folder. Neither ASP.NET MVC nor ASP.NET Web API gives a S..T about the physical location of the controllers. All it cares is that they are present at runtime in the AppDomain and that they respect the standard naming conventions and base types.

Comment: Speaking of naming conventions, what should I name the controllers? In my case, I don't think ItemController and ItemsController is a good idea, should I call one ItemsApiController? Is this what most experienced developers are doing now?

Comment: No, as soon as the API controllers are in a sub-folder you don't need to be including the `Api` token in their names. In RESTful conventions the name of the controller is the name of your resource. So if your resource is called `Item` then your controller should be called `ItemsController`.